# How to detect taps on MKMapView but ignore taps on MKAnnotationViews

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkmapview, uitapgesturerecognizer, mkmapviewdelegate

I'm writing an iOS app where the user taps on an `MKMapView` to drop a pin (`MKAnnotationView` subclass), and taps an existing pin to delete it.

Adding new pins and deleting old ones is working, but the tap to delete an existing pin is *also* resulting in a new pin being dropped.

**How can I update my code so the `UITapGestureRecognizer` detect taps on the map but ignore taps on map annotations?**

I'm currently detecting taps on the `MKMapView` using a `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
@objc func tapHandler(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer)
  {
    let location = recogniser.location(in: self.parent.mapView)
    let coordinate = self.parent.mapView.convert(location, toCoordinateFrom: self.parent.mapView)
    parent.shapeCoordinates.append(coordinate)
    self.redrawTheMap()
  }
```

I'm detecting taps on the pin using `MKMapViewDelegate`:

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)
  {
    if let myAnnotation = view.annotation as? CustomAnnotation
    {
      parent.shapeCoordinates.remove(at: myAnnotation.index)
      self.redrawTheMap()
    }
  }
```

At the moment the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is picking up all taps on the `MKMapView`, regardless of whether they are on an `MKAnnotationView` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally worked it out for myself. The trick was to use the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to intercept the tap and decide whether or not the `UITapGestureRecognizer` should handle it.

The following delegate method code checks what has been tapped on, and ignores it if it's an `MKPinAnnotationView`:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool
  {
    if (touch.view.self?.isKind(of: MKPinAnnotationView.self) == true)
    {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
```

Comment: You could just return !(touch.view.self?.isKind(of: MKPinAnnotationView.self). No real need for the if-statement